# ReCaptcha input not rendered in form after ajax request

Tags: ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, recaptcha

I am using [recapcha](https://github.com/ambethia/recaptcha/) gem in my create users form. The form is submitting by ajax using *data-remote=true* attribute and then a *create.js.erb* template is rendered.

The idea is after, submitting the form:

1. if the user creation **is** successful to render a proper message
2. if the user creation **is not** successful to render the form again
   with the corresponding errors

The issue is that, when a error appears (wrong recaptcha code for example) - the recaptcha input field is not rendered.

For now, in the *create.js.erb* file I have only the following line:

```
$('#b-register').html('<%=j render partial: 'security_users/sign_in' %>');
```

Why the  @securirty_user object is automatically passed back to the partial when I am not using locals?
When I am rendering the same partial on error that I used initially, why the recaptcha input is missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to have a "sign in" form with recapthca which is using ajax, you should not re-rendered the form.

What you should do is the following:

1. Make *create.js.erb* view to handle ajax request and in the controller add *format.js*.
2. In the new view instantiate JavaScript object which is holding the errors like this:

> var current_errors = <%=  raw @security_user.errors.to_json %>;

Then you are free to handle the errors as you want - add new elements displaying the error text or other, but if there is only one error:

1. Clear the password fields
2. Reload the recaptcha like this:

> Recaptcha.reload();